# How to return a new dataframe excluding certain columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, indexing

I am trying to take a dataframe `df` and return a new dataframe excluding any columns with the word `'job'` in its name, excluding any columns with the string `'birth'` in its name, and excluding these columns: `name`, `userID`, `lgID`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Pandas `str` methods to create Boolean masks, then filter a `pd.Index` object:

```
L = ['jobs', 'careers', 'birth', 'birthdate', 'name', 'userID', 'lgID', 'value1', 'value2']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=L)

m1 = df.columns.str.contains('job|birth')         # regex supported
m2 = df.columns.isin(['name', 'userID', 'lgID'])  # use isin for exact matches

idx = df.columns[~(m1 | m2)]

Index(['careers', 'value1', 'value2'], dtype='object')
```

Then filter your dataframe:

```
df = df[idx]
```

Comment: is this for including them or excluding them?

Comment: @Sang, excluding them, check the example I've given. `~` stands for negation.

Comment: it didn't work for me for some reason...df is already existing dataframe, and I want to take that and create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a list of the columns you don't want using a list comprehension, looks like in your case you might get:

```
exclude_columns = [x for x in df.columns if "birth" not in x] + ["name", "userID", "IgID"]
```

Then you can get the difference of those columns and the ones in your df

```
df_new = df[df.columns.difference(exclude_columns)]
```

Answer (score 1):

To build on @sven-harris answer.

List the columns:

`remove = [x for x in df.columns if 'job' in x or 'birth' in x]

remove += ['name', 'userID', 'IgID']`

`df = df.drop(remove, axis=1)  # axis=1 to drop columns, 0 for rows.`